# HWPFDocument / XWPFDocument New Lines

Tags: java, apache-poi

I am trying to pull data from microsoft-word and translate it to sql statement and inserting it an Oracle database.

When the data in ms-word contains a new line that is created by [Shift-Enter] and not just enter,

The text contains an icon that looks like a box with a question mark.

[image]

Where the ET is just standard new line using the enter key and the ST is new lines using the

Shift-Enter combination. So when generating the SQL and inserting it to oracle, oracle counts that not as a text, but as hex.

My question is, how to remove lines that is created by [shift-enter] to just a standard '\n'?

Thanks

*Update*
This is how i get the text information

```
POIFSFileSystem fs = new POIFSFileSystem(new FileInputStream(file));
HWPFDocument doc = new HWPFDocument(fs);
WordExtractor we = new WordExtractor(doc);
text = we.getText();
```

Update Answer:
This was a bug in poi-3.6. In poi-3.8 it shows as \r.

Comment: Some of the Microsoft Office formats use \r rather than \n for their new lines, could that be the case for your file?

Comment: @Gagravarr I've tried replacing \r, but all that does it replaces the new line.

Comment: How are you getting the text out of the word file in the first place? And can you send the text through a hexdumper to work out what those mystery characters are?

Comment: @Gagravarr I believe the text is generated by going to word document (.doc) and using [Shift +  Enter] rather than just Enter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're almost certainly seeing are "fields" in the word document, which are special blocks of text such as links, macros etc

Option number one is to continue using WordExtractor, but call [stripFields(String)](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/hwpf/extractor/WordExtractor.html#stripFields%28java.lang.String%29) on the resulting text before using it. That'll remove any of these fields from the text for you.

The other option is to use a different way of getting the text out. [WordToTextConverter](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/hwpf/converter/WordToTextConverter.html) is part of Apache POI, and is more complex code that handles more of the format and should skip these for you (WordExtractor is pretty simple and low level). The other is to use [Apache Tika](http://tika.apache.org/), which provides a common way of extracting text from a number of file formats. That does have the proper code to deal with fields, and as an added bonus it'll be trivial for you to support .docx or .pdf when your requirements change!

Comment: So as far as StripFields(String) goes, that didn't work for the end of paragraph lines, but i'll try word to text converter

Comment: I wanted to vote up and its locked. can you edit something simple on your answer?

Comment: And, i figured now that the poi-3.6 jar its a bug and the poi-3.8 jar displays \r rather than that weird ? symbol.

Comment: You probably want 3.9, that has quite a few bug fixes since 3.8